# switch images on hover jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow, slide

Well it definitely seems that internet does not have solution for this yet.

I need to rotate / fade / slide ten or so img that are stacked on top of each other on hover. In this manner

```
$(function(){
$('.preview img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  $('.preview :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.preview');}, 
  200);
});
```

except i need to kick it and stop it with hover which i do not manage to accomplish. I've tried to add active class etc but it just flips out when started with hover

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net demo with your HTML and images from http://lorempixel.com or http://placehold.it.

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` method returns a handle that you can use to stop the interval:

```
$(function(){
  $('.preview img:gt(0)').hide();

  var handle;

  $('.preview').mouseover(function(){
    handle= setInterval(function(){
      $('.preview :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.preview');}, 
    200);
  });

  $('.preview').mouseout(function(){
    clearInterval(handle);
  });

});
```